# How to delete specific files & folders from newly created git branch in GITLAB dashboard?

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab, git-branch

I'm a newbie to Git and I'm doing all the Git operations by logging-in at Gitlab URL using the Gitlab dashboard UI and menus.

I'm using **Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS** on my local machine.

I have no idea about how to use command line for Git operations.

So I just created new branch from '`master`' branch of my project. I want to delete specific files and folders from this newly created branch. I searched for menus/options in the Gitlab UI but I couldn't find it. I can see the files and folders when I click on 'Files' menu of my branch in Gitlab UI.

Can someone please suggest me how to delete specific files and folders from the newly created git branch?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that what the .gitignore file is for?

But if you already uploaded the files, delete them from your local folder and then commit and push, and they will be deleted.

Comment: Actually before the branch files are downloaded I want to remove the specific files and folders. In other words I don't want to share all of my project files and folders with the prospective user.That's my concern. .gitignore is to prevent committing certain files and folders, I know that.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to delete specific files and folders from this newly created branch. I searched for menus/options in the Gitlab UI but I couldn't find it.

It can depend on the version of GitLab you are using, but with GitLab 8.0+, you do have a button remove when selecting a file:

[image: Remove]

That would create one commit per deleted file though, meaning it does not scale well if you have hundreds of files to remove. In that latter case, a local clone and local `git rm`, followed by a `git add -A` and *one* `git commit` (and a `git push`, of course).

---

> In other words I don't want to share all of my project files and folders with the prospective user

Keep in mind those files are *still* available in the history of the repo.
If you share with your user an *archive* (a zip of the working tree at a given commit, without any history), *then* those files would not be available:

Still in "Files" in GitLab:

[image: archive]

Select your branch and the format of the archive, and download the content of that branch at its latest commit.